# Дата на русском

Tags: php

Нужно что бы месяц выводился на русском языке

```
$date = date('d F Y');
echo "Сегодня — ".$date;
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Исправить дату на русский язык в php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/530427/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%b2-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

То что у вас написано в комментариях как ответы - так делать не нужно. Как делать нужно - существует расширение для `php` - `intl` . Убедитесь что оно у вас включено `php -m`

В нем существует специальный `IntlDateFormatter`, который вы инициализируете с нужными вам настройками.

```php
$date = new DateTime();
$intlFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter('ru_RU', IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
$intlFormatter->setPattern('MMMM');

echo $intlFormatter->format($date);
```

По форматеру документация [тут](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php)
По паттернам можно посмотреть [тут](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Comment: Так вот вместо того чтобы плодить дубликаты - ответил бы в оригинальном вопросе.

Comment: @u_mulder у тебя есть все возможности сделать это за меня :)

Answer (score 0):

[strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strftime.php)
`%B` - Полное название месяца, в соответствии с настройками локали

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'russian');
echo iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', strftime('%B')); // Сентябрь
```